# python datetie.time object set timezone from GPS data

Tags: python, gps, nmea

So I'm kinda hopeless here,

I've tried in the pass 5 hours to set the timezone for a `datetime.time` object, received from a GPS...

I currently have the following (working) code:

```
import serial
import string
import pynmea2

ser = serial.Serial()
ser.port = "/dev/ttyS0"
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.timeout = 1
ser.open()

while True:
    data = ser.readline()
    if (data.startswith("$GPGGA")):
        formatted = pynmea2.parse(data)
        #  print(data)
        print('Latitude: {}'.format(formatted.lat))
        print('Longitude: {}'.format(formatted.lon))
        print('Timestamp: {}'.format(formatted.timestamp))
        print('Signal Quality: {}'.format(formatted.gps_qual))
        print('Number sats: {}'.format(formatted.num_sats))
```

However, I want to have the `formatted.timestamp`, which currently is returned as `00:00:00`, for example `19:03:51`, to be in another timezone (`Europe/Brussels`).

How can I achieve this?

I tried alot already, but nothing seems to work here....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the original timezone (e.g. US Eastern), you can use [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#pytz-world-timezone-definitions-for-python).

First you set the timezone with `localize()` and then use `astimezone()` to convert to your desired timezone. Also, you will need to format your datetime from the available data (this is just using a simple string).

Would something like this be helpful?

```py
import datetime
import pytz

tz_eastern = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
tz_brussels = pytz.timezone('Europe/Brussels')

time_date_string = '2019-08-20 19:03:51'

brussels_time = tz_eastern.localize(
    datetime.datetime.strptime(time_date_string,
                               '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))\
    .astimezone(tz_brussels)\
    .strftime("%H:%M:%S")

print(f'{time_date_string.split(" ")[1]} is the original time string'
      f'\n{brussels_time} is the {tz_brussels} time')
```

Outputs:

```
19:03:51 is the original time string
01:03:51 is the Europe/Brussels time
```

Comment: The thing here is, that I don't have a date and I can't rely on the system time. Modified your code to fit my purpose is the follwoing output: https://pastebin.com/w3aSN6ca However, now it's 11:12 here and the output is 09:28, so the time is completely wrong here...
In addition, the system does **not** have internet.

Comment: If you don't use a date `datetime` defaults to `1900-01-01` and the time will be wrong. You could hard code a date like `2019-01-01` and it will provide a correct time.